# Use user chosen Struct in another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a file containing structs (each strucht contains an array).

I want to be able to use the Struct the user has chosen in another View! Sorry if I can't explain myself.

Here is the code:

This is the one containing the "Workouts"

```
import Foundation

struct Routines {
let routineName: String
let videoFileName: String
let description: Array<Any>
let thumbnailFileName: String

static func fetchRoutines() -> [Routines] {
    let v1 = Routines(routineName: "Recommended Routine", videoFileName: "v1", description: Workout1.fetchWorkout1(), thumbnailFileName: "v8")
    let v2 = Routines(routineName: "Routine Extra", videoFileName: "v2", description: Workout2.fetchWorkout2(), thumbnailFileName: "v2")

    return [v1, v2]
}
}

struct Workout1 {

let excerciseName: String
let sets: Int
let reps: Int

static func fetchWorkout1() -> [Workout1] {

    let w1 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Bench Press", sets: 3, reps: 8)
    let w2 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Push Press", sets: 3, reps: 8)
    let w3 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Squat", sets: 3, reps: 8)
    let w4 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Deadlift", sets: 3, reps: 8)
    let w5 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Bicep Curl", sets: 3, reps: 8)
    let w6 = Workout1(excerciseName: "Tricep Pushdown", sets: 3, reps: 8)



    return [w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6]
}


}

struct Workout2 {

let excerciseName: String
let sets: Int
let reps: Int

static func fetchWorkout2() -> [Workout2] {

    let e1 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Bench Press", sets: 5, reps: 15)
    let e2 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Push Press", sets: 3, reps: 3)
    let e3 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Squat", sets: 5, reps: 5)
    let e4 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Deadlift", sets: 3, reps: 3)
    let e5 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Bicep Curl", sets: 5, reps: 15)
    let e6 = Workout2(excerciseName: "Tricep Pushdown", sets: 5, reps: 15)



    return [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6]
}

}
```

This is the class where the ViewController takes the info and shows some info from the "Workouts or Routines"

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class WorkoutsListViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4274509804, green: 0.4745098039, blue: 0.5764705882, alpha: 1)

}

var routines: [Routines] = Routines.fetchRoutines()
var workoutSelected = [Any]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return routines.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutsListTableViewCell
    let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
    cell.routine = routine
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
    print(routine.routineName)
    workoutSelected = routine.description
    print(workoutSelected)
    /*WorkoutsListViewController.workoutSelected = routine.description
    print(WorkoutsListViewController.workoutSelected)
    */


    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToWorkout", sender: self)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}


}
```

And here is where I want to be able to use that array and display the info!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class WorkoutViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8352941176, green: 0.8352941176, blue: 0.8352941176, alpha: 1)
}


var workouts: [Workout1] = Workout1.fetchWorkout1()
//var workoutSelected = WorkoutsListViewController.workoutSelected



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return workouts.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutCell", for: indexPath)
    let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = workout.excerciseName
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

    return cell


}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("Do \(workout.sets) sets of \(workout.reps) reps of \(workout.excerciseName)")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAt` pass the index path as `sender` parameter of `performSegue`, nothing else

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToWorkout", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Then override `prepare(for segue` to pass the workout array to the destination controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToWorkout" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! WorkoutViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
        destinationController.workouts = routine.description
    }
}
```

---

By the way your structs are pretty confusing. Why not **one** struct for both workout arrays, this avoids the ugly `Any` declaration

```
struct Workout {

    let excerciseName: String
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int

    static func fetchWorkout1() -> [Workout] {
        return [Workout(excerciseName: "Bench Press", sets: 3, reps: 8),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Push Press", sets: 3, reps: 8),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Squat", sets: 3, reps: 8),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Deadlift", sets: 3, reps: 8),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Bicep Curl", sets: 3, reps: 8),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Tricep Pushdown", sets: 3, reps: 8)]
    }

    static func fetchWorkout2() -> [Workout] {
        return [Workout(excerciseName: "Bench Press", sets: 5, reps: 15),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Push Press", sets: 3, reps: 3),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Squat", sets: 5, reps: 5),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Deadlift", sets: 3, reps: 3),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Bicep Curl", sets: 5, reps: 15),
                Workout(excerciseName: "Tricep Pushdown", sets: 5, reps: 15)]
    }
}
```

Then declare in `Routines`

```
let description: [Workout]
```

and in `WorkoutViewController`

```
var workouts = [Workout]()
```

And you have to reload the table view at some point for example in `viewWillAppear` but never with the `didSet` observer.

Comment: No luck. I think there is the problem:

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
    print(routine.routineName)
    workoutSelected = routine.description
    print(workoutSelected)
    /*WorkoutsListViewController.workoutSelected = routine.description
    print(WorkoutsListViewController.workoutSelected)
    */


    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToWorkout", sender: self)
    }

The routine.description is not getting the [].

Comment: No luck means what? Please use my suggested code. Getting the routine in `didSelectRowAt ` is not needed.

Comment: The app crashes.

 Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1162c9a20) to 'BodyweightFitness.WorkoutViewController' (0x109b96348).
2019-02-13 20:23:41.091293+0100 BodyweightFitness[30764:20025883] Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1162c9a20) to 'BodyweightFitness.WorkoutViewController' (0x109b96348).

Comment: Solved.

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToWorkout" {
            let destinationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
            let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
            let dvc = destinationController.topViewController as! WorkoutViewController
            svc.workouts = routine.description
        }
    }

Answer (score -1):

Solved! Thanks to @vadrian.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToWorkout" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
        let dvc = destinationController.topViewController as! WorkoutViewController
        svc.workouts = routine.description
    }
}
```